# how to bring back java script array to its original order

Tags: javascript

I've an array in this order

**Original order of array:**

```
var originalcolumns = [
                "es_officer_id",
                "es_officer_name",
                "es_officer_fname",
                "es_bps_title",
                "es_department_name",
                "es_bps_id",
                "es_department_id"
             ]

var sortedfirst = originalcolumns.sort();
```

**After sorting the sortedfirst array looks like**

```
[
  "es_bps_id",
  "es_bps_title",
  "es_department_id",
  "es_department_name",
  "es_officer_fname",
  "es_officer_id",
  "es_officer_name"
]
```

**A copy of array (stripped the value after last underscore)**

I'll match each record to its next one if it return true, the alias will be same as you can see in the end result.

```
var withoutlast = [
              "es_bps",
              "es_bps",
              "es_department",
              "es_department",
              "es_officer",
              "es_officer",
              "es_officer"
            ]

var withoutlastsorted = withoutlast.sort();
```

**1: it is crucial to understand my table name is es_officer so the very first alias should be with es_officer_id like (a.es_officer_id) which is NOT working so far because i sorted the array alphabetically.**

**2: same initials must have same aliases for ex: a.es_officer_id will have same alias as a.es_officer_name, i hit the wall in this case too. If i dont sort the array and add aliases as it is than result top 3 results have same alias because they are in a row.  But last 4 will have different aliases fot ex: b c, d, e**

Now adding some aliases to each item in array

```
var alias = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',
                     'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

var AliasAddedCols = [];
var aliasIndex = 0;
var sameColIndex = 0;

for(var columnName in sortedfirst)
{
    AliasAddedCols.push(alias[aliasIndex] +'.'+sortedfirst[columnName]);
    if(withoutlast[sameColIndex] !== withoutlast[sameColIndex + 1])
    {
       aliasIndex ++;
    }
    sameColIndex++;
}
```

now if i console AliasAddedCols the end result looks like this:

```
[
   "a.es_bps_id",
   "a.es_bps_title",
   "b.es_department_id",
   "b.es_department_name",
   "c.es_officer_fname",
   "c.es_officer_id",
   "c.es_officer_name"
]
```

**The only problem is i need the order of last array which is "AliasAddedCols" to be exactly like the order "original array".**

**Also the alias is starting from es_bps_id which in my case it is wrong, first alias "a" should be with top 3 columns (es_officer_id, es_officer_name, es_officer_fname) the second alias "b" should be with item 4 and 6 (es_bps_title, es_bps_id) and the third alias "c" should be with item 5 and 7 in array (es_department_name, es_department_id**

Comment: `Array.sort()` will mutate the original array so you best start with a `.slice().sort()`

Comment: What is it that you actually want to achieve? If you don't want to change the order of your array, don't sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest these steps:

1. Wrap each of the strings within a single-element sub-array;
2. Get a shallow copy of that array;
3. Sort that copy by the string part (like you did);
4. Add the prefix according to your logic (like you did);
5. The order of elements in the array of step 1 did not change, so now just unwrap the (replaced) strings again.

Here is the ES6 code for that (but without destructuring assignments in function parameters, as you found that was not supported in your environment):

```js
var columns = [
    "es_officer_id",
    "es_officer_name",
    "es_officer_fname",
    "es_bps_title",
    "es_department_name",
    "es_bps_id",
    "es_department_id"
];

// 0. Define the table name, which should be sorted first
var tablePrefix = 'es_officer_';
// 1. Convert to array of arrays (to wrap the strings)
columns = columns.map( (s, i) => [s] );
// 2. Create a shallow copy
columns.slice()
       // Sort that copy, but keep table name first 
       .sort( (a, b) => a[0].indexOf(tablePrefix) ? a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) : -1 )
       // Alter the strings according to your logic
       .reduce( (status, a) => {
            // Chop off last "_word"
            var base = a[0].replace(/_[^_]*$/, '');
            // When different than previous, increase counter
            if (status.prev !== base) status.charCode++;
            status.prev = base;
            // Prefix string with letter
            a[0] = String.fromCharCode(status.charCode) + '.' + a[0];
            // Pass status on to next iteration
            return status;
       }, { charCode: 'a'.charCodeAt(0)-1 } ); // set initial status
// 3. `columns` still has the original order, now perform the 
//    inverse of step 1, unwrapping the strings
columns = columns.map( (a, i) => a[0] );

console.log(columns);
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what i need.

Comment: this is strange, it is giving me error i don't know why, I'm using this in node api.  .sort( ([s1], [s2]) => s1.localeCompare(s2) ) SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: OK, that is because ES6 is not fully supported then. I will provide a version without this feature in a minute.

Comment: awesome thankyou, and there is one more thing i missed, the numbers added before the dots are actually single alphabet. for ex: a.es_officer_id

Comment: and it can be random nos, for ex if there are seven items then it can be a.es_officer_id, a.es_officer_name, a.es_officer_fname, b.es_bps_title, c.es_department_name, b.es_bps_id, c.es_department_id

Comment: there is one thing common es_bps_id and es_bps_title will have same alphabet. fo ex: b.es_bps_id, b.es_bps

Comment: But your issue is not with that prefix is it? If you want me to include that, then please provide the code you have for setting that prefix ***in your question***, and I will integrate it.

Comment: In the meanwhile I isolated the logic of adding the prefix in a separate function in my answer, so you can easily put your own logic there instead.

Comment: I see no change in your question... in the meanwhile I put a slightly different algorithm, which does not require a sort operation to get back to the original order.

Comment: sorry for the late editing my machine completely crashed, i don't know why but anyway i have edited the question and I've seen your updated answer as well let me try that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: can you please take a look at last two paragraphs of my question

Comment: alias a should be starting from es_officer_id NOT es_bps_id but it is because i'm sorting it first that why its starting with es_bps_id.... I don't know how to do it, my logic is poor

Comment: there is an error let base = a[0].replace(/_[^_]*$/, ''); Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

Comment: Just replace `let` with `var`. It is not an error, but you are apparently not using strict mode. I strongly suggest you move to that when you have time. It will open up more ES6 possibilities.

Comment: Please tell me what is the sort order. I don't understand what kind of sort order would put `es_officer` first.You want an exception for only that, or do you have in general other exceptions to the sort order?

Answer (score 1):

Just store the original array as a separate value, then you can transform it to whatever you need the values to be.

Please be aware that `Array.prototype.sort()` does it's job "in-place", which means you have to create a copy of your original array. You can use `var copy = myArray.slice()` or spread operator `var copy = [ ...myArray ]` (ES2015+).

Answer (score 1):

Just with two reduces, you might do as follows;

```js
var columns = [
               "es_officer_id",
               "es_officer_name",
               "es_officer_fname",
               "es_bps_title",
               "es_department_name",
               "es_bps_id",
               "es_department_id"
             ];
    sorted = [
              "0.es_bps_id",
              "1.es_bps_title",
              "2.es_department_id",
              "3.es_department_name",
              "4.es_officer_fname",
              "5.es_officer_id",
              "6.es_officer_name"
             ],
            lut = columns.reduce((m,e,i) => (m[e] = i,m),{});
       restored = sorted.reduce((res,e) => (res[lut[e.split(/[0-9a-zA-Z]+\./)[1]]] = e,res) ,[]);
console.log(restored);
```

Comment: hey thanks for your code, but i just made a mistake, the number before the dot is actually single alphabet, and it can be random alpha, for ex if there are seven items then it can be a.es_officer_id, a.es_officer_name, a.es_officer_fname, b.es_bps_title, c.es_department_name, b.es_bps_id, c.es_department_id

Comment: there is one thing common es_bps_id and es_bps_title will have same alphabet. fo ex: b.es_bps_id, b.es_bps

Comment: Then you might do like `restored = sorted.reduce((res,e) => (res[lut[e.split(/[0-9a-zA-Z]+\./)[1]]] = e,res) ,[]);`